# Events in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, events

I read that there aren't events in ASP.Net MVC.
However, I added button and when I double click it a buttonClick event was made.
So, are there events in Asp.Net MVC or not?

Comment: is this supposed to be a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are using the webforms view engine. This view engine includes all the page life cycle stuff from the webforms framework. That means that you can, theoretically, use anything from webforms in asp.net mvc if you are using the webforms view engine. However, I'd strongly suggest that you don't do that. You will miss out on all the advantages with asp.net mvc and you'd be better of just using webforms in the first place.

If you are new to asp.net mvc I'd suggest that you'd use another viewengine instead as that will help you learn the framework a lot better and faster. There is a viewengine from Microsoft called [Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx) that you could start with.

Comment: And I also read that there aren't rich controls, but I clearly see the calendar. Is this because of the webforms view engine also? How do I turn it off?

Comment: The toolbox is for webforms and not for asp.net mvc. You shouldn't use anything from the toolbox. You _can_, however, use anything from the toolbox in the webforms view engine. But if you do, you might just as well use webforms.

Answer (score 0):

There are not server control events like there are in webforms. There are jQuery and javascript events that can happen in the HTML/DOM though.

If you double clicked a button on a designer canvas in visual studio, and it created a button click method in another file with a signature like public void MyEvent(EventArgs e), then you are not working with an MVC project.

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing a buttonClick event handler created when you double-click a button, you are likely attempting to use the Button server control.  Instead you should simply include an `<input type="submit" value="Button Text" />` element within a `<form>`.  The form's action will result in the controller's action method being called on the subsequent post request.

I highly suggest that you do some do some research on ASP.NET MVC.  There are several good resources, but here's a short introductory video to start with:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-2/how-do-i/5-minute-introduction-to-aspnet-mvc